# Blocked vs Non-blocked Pop-up window

Tags: javascript, browser, popupwindow

I found that, browsers don't block all pop-up JavaScript windows.

How to write pop-up windows in JavaScript that won't be blocked by browsers?

I mean what is the main factor that makes the difference?

Comment: Someone, please rename this question for more readability and understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main factor for deciding what popup window will be blocked is the good pop-up window **must be show after user do some action** like click or do some other event like press enter.

However, you can use in-page pop-up window like [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) that all pop-up blocker cannot block it because it just is html tag like span or div. Therefore, it does not clever enough for understanding content inside pop-up tag. It should be the best way to avoid all pop-up blockers.

Answer (score 8):

In Firefox (and most other modern web browsers with popup blockers) Javascript windows are typically allowed if they are the result of a user click, but stopped if they are trying to open in the background.

Compare the method used in these [bad popups](http://popuptest.com/popuptest1.html) with these [good popups](http://popuptest.com/goodpopups.html). Source code is available on the site. Here is the source code for the "good" popups:

```
<a href="javascript:winopen('http://www.popuptest.com/popup3.html','blank','width=450,height=235,status=yes')">Good PopUp #1</a>
<br><br>
<A class=blu HREF="http://www.popuptest.com/popup2.html" target="_BLANK">Good PopUp #2</A>
<br><br>
<A class=black HREF="http://www.popuptest.com/popup3.html" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'rank','450','450','yes','center');return false" onfocus="this.blur()">Good PopUp #3</A>
<br><br>
<a href="javascript:PopWindow('http://www.popuptest.com/popup4.html', 450, 320)">Good PopUp #4</A>
```

Comment: Only two of those popup links looks remotely good, the rest are inaccessible.