# Every time the Popup window is blocked

Tags: javascript, html

In my application we are using popup window
Ex. window.open();
while i am trying to log in, every time the Popup window is blocked in IE 7, IE 8 and IE 9.

how to disable it using JavaScript code.

thanks in advance..,

Comment: Please read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587677/avoid-browser-pop-up-blockers)

Comment: User triggered popup windows won't be blocked. **Auto-open** popups are likely to be blocked. Are yours user-triggered or auto-open?

Comment: disable your popupblocker on IE..

Comment: @techfoobar my popup windows is User triggered,

Comment: dude, we can't control browser settings via Javascript

Comment: to overcome this, people use popup divisions. For example, Fancybox. http://fancybox.net/

Comment: @dark - but some of the social websites allow to open popup windows, event we enable the popup blocker.

Comment: so, how are you triggering the popup? I mean is it a Click or Key Press or What?

Comment: user triggered it is click..,

Answer (score 1):

Popup blocker is supposed to stop popup windows attached to such events as `onload` and `onunload` (and other events not directly associated with the person requesting a popup) from appearing but is not supposed to block those attached to an `onclick` event on a link (and other events that can be taken to mean that the person has requested it).

Not all browsers are smart enough to realize that if the `onclick` event on a link calls a function and the purpose of that function is to open a popup window that the popup has in fact been requested. They see the popup code in the function but are not clever enough to see that this code is called as a result of an action by the person using the browser. Coding our popup that way leads to the popup being blocked despite the fact that it was requested, a sure way to get someone annoyed that your site doesn't work properly despite the fact that the problem is actually their browser.

The way to fix this for many of these dumb browsers is to place the popup code into the `onclick` itself instead of calling a function.

For Example,

```
<a href="some_page.html" onclick="window.open('some_other_page.html')">Open Popup</a>
```

Here are some previous posts that might help you,

[Bypass popup blocker on window.open when JQuery event.preventDefault() is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set)

[Blocked vs Non-blocked Pop-up window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816127/blocked-vs-non-blocked-pop-up-window)